# Зачем ставят запятую в сравнительный оборот в составе сказуемого?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. *От ярости и напряжения его мышцы натянулись(,) как канаты*.
2. *Каждая мышца натянулась(,) точно тетива.*
3. *Яшку едва оттащили от большого, здоровенного бурлака, в которого он вцепился(,) точно кошка.*

Comment: Вообще говоря, я бы такие вопросы отправляла на редактирование, он совершенно невнятный.  Спрашивается про запятые, а их в предложении нет (скобочки только стоят). Как можно «поставить запятую в сравнительный оборот в составе сказуемого»? И где здесь сказуемое с точки зрения автора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятую в сравнительный оборот в составе сказуемого (перед сравнительным союзом) не ставят. Если там есть запятая, то это уже не сравнительный оборот в составе сказуемого.

Подробнее см справочник Лопатина, [§ 88](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg88.php) и [§ 90](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg90.php).

Comment: Прочитал эти параграфы и сделал выводы, что все же эти запятые были совсем не обязательны. Если бы, например, вам дали эти предложения с просьбой расставить запятые, поставили бы их так же?

Comment: @Theej что значит "поставил бы" или "не поставил бы"? Эти предложения с запятыми и без запятых — *разные* предложения с *разным* смыслом. "Мышцы натянулись, как канаты" — факт того, что мышцы натянулись, сравнивается с тем фактом, что канаты тоже натягиваются. "Мышцы натянулись как канаты" — указывает, что характер натягивания мышц подобен натягиванию канатов. Во втором случае можно было бы сказать:  мышцы "по-канаточьи" натянулись, — если бы в русском языке была такая форма.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @Theej мы тут недавно и горячо обсуждали выделенный оборот, начинающийся союзом "как" (и подобными), так что можете почитать вопрос и ответы: https://clck.ru/avxLj Основная суть — в двух ответах Sharon на собственный вопрос, где она подводит итоги диспуту и отвечает на его положения, так что все сотни комментариев можно проигнорировать, но если захотите их читать, предупреждаю: опасно для моСКа, диспут получился очень душным :)

Comment: Обязательно посмотрю вечером)

Answer (score 2):

А я бы так оформила предложения:

*От ярости и напряжения его мышцы натянулись **как канаты**.*

*Каждая мышца натянулась, **точно тетива**.*

*Яшку едва оттащили от большого, здоровенного бурлака, в которого он вцепился,  **точно кошка**.*

И такие замечания:

1. Интересно мне было, как ответят  на этот вопрос. Он не кажется настолько **однозначным**, что его можно так быстро и коротко решить по справочнику Лопатина.
2. Обстоятельство образа действия, выраженные сравнительным оборотом, **не входит в состав сказуемого** и при этом не обособляется.
3. **А разные союзы** (КАК и ТОЧНО) разве ни о чем не говорят? Про контекст я уж и не вспоминаю...
4. **О расстановке ударений**, которое фактически во многих случаях определяет решение, тоже ничего не сказано. При обособлении ударение падает и на глагол, и на оборот, а без него – только на оборот.

Comment: Я полагаю *как, будто, словно, точно* синонимичными, за исключением случаев отождествления ("как" ="в качестве"). Просто "как" более популярен.

Comment: Да ничего, пожалуйста, просто у Розенталя материал по этим союзам вынесен в отдельную тему. Обороты с ними обособляются намного чаще, и это неудивительно: это как бы "художественные" союзы со значением уподобления. Да и все предложения различаются по структуре, а при таком оформлении выглядят как близнецы-братья.

Comment: а ещё есть "наподобие", который вроде бы похож на этот синонимичный ряд, но при этом не обособляется...

Comment: Наподобие – это предлог, но не союз же.  Предложный оборот  является несогласованным определением: Зверек наподобие мыши. Это  не тема сравнительных союзов, там свои правила обособления.